# Not able to use svgForEveryone for Salesforce Lightning Design System

Tags: lightning-aura-components, internet-explorer, lightning-design-system, slds

I'm developing an app for Salesforce1 platform using Lightning Components and the UI framework is Lightning Design System.

I'm partially successful implementing the SVG icons in different browsers. The suggested way to support SVG in IE is to include svgForEveryone.js file. After including the file, it throw '<' unexpected token.

I thought of modifying the library, basially '<' is an if-condition but just a raincheck to ask in the forum before i modify the library or look for something else.

In any case i would put the fallback code to show png images, where svg is not supported.

If it has been resolved, any help would be appreciated, before i move on from svgForEveryone.js file.

Please refer to the link below, where i'm stuck to implement svg for IE.
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/icons/

Thanks,